# Why does the donation process not produce a receipt either on screen or dispatched by email to donor?

Tags: civicontribute

We have joomla 3.6.2, CiviCrm 4.7.10 and PayPal Express (PP)
Donor receives an email from PP stating you sent a payment to ....
Donor should also receive an emailed receipt from CiviCrm but does not
Donor should also be returned from PP to an online receipt but is not, instead sees a red error page.

Where do I start looking for the answer!??

error message is
CiviCRM-001 -   @import url(/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. Failed to update contribution in database

[Return to home page.](http://gsv.org.au/)

function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Comment: Are other email functions of your CiviCRM install working?  Can you successfully send a Mass email or an email to one individual?

Comment: We would be better able to help you if you updated your question to paste in the contents of the error page you mention.

Comment: Mass mail is working and can send a test email from both joomla and civi,

Comment: error message is

Answer (score 1):

'Failed to update contribution in database' tells us that your Contribution is never fully completed on the CiviCRM side of things - and hence it will not get to the part where CiviCRM sends out a receipt.

In other words - the monies are processed on the PayPal side of things - but when CiviCRM hears about it - and is trying to record that the transaction was successful - it runs into a Failed to update.

Comment: Ok!  Why though is it not fully completing....

Comment: I'm not sure - but this is definitively why the receipt is not going out. Look in the ConfigAndLog for clues / backtrace of the "Failed to update contribution in database"